# What is the purpose of advertising a VOLUME in the Dockerfile if it can be omitted?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I noticed by accident that it doesn't make a difference whether I advertise a VOLUME in the Dockerfile or not. (The Oracle database xe18.4 lacks the VOLUME statement) When I `docker run -v ...` the volume gets created without error.

What's the purpose of advertising a VOLUME in the Dockerfile if it can be omitted just as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the purpose of advertising a VOLUME in the Dockerfile if it can be omitted just as well?

It means that when you run the container, any files created at that location are stored in a volume, rather than in the container root filesystem. This means that those files can be shared with other containers using e.g. `--volumes-from` (or an explicit reference to the volume).

It's also an explicit source of documentation -- if you want to persist storage beyond the lifecycle of your container, the `VOLUME` directive is telling you where you should mount your named volume or bind mount.

Comment: Just to make sure: _"It means that when you run the container, any files created at that location are stored in a volume, rather than in the container root filesystem."_ - From my experience this also happens just by running the container with a volume declaration - even when the Dockerfile lacks a VOLUME statement. Isn't that the case? What's the exact difference to this regard?

Comment: The difference is that a `VOLUME` directive gets you a  volume even if you don't explicitly declare one on the command line.